# Custom Logger Class python: How to make it work across classes?

Tags: python, logging

I've been playing around with a custom logger class, which I created in order to have another "verbosity level" (which is trace) implemented.
I am aware, that it is not recommended according to the documentation of the logger class - however I have code, which has to have it in order to do extensive debugging.
That beeing said, I can call the logger with all methods (LOG.warning, LOG.trace, etc) as expected, but when I try to do the same in another class it does not work as intended. I guess the properties of the logger just get lost for some reason.

Basically what I want to achieve is, that the properties which I set initially (like the log format, log handlers, log level etc) are retained in every class.

I have a logger class, which implements "TRACE":

```
from logging import getLoggerClass, addLevelName, setLoggerClass, NOTSET


class AioLogger(getLoggerClass()) :
    TRACE = 1

    def __init__(self, name, level=NOTSET):
        super().__init__(name, level)

    addLevelName(TRACE, "TRACE")

    def trace(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(AioLogger.TRACE):
            self._log(AioLogger.TRACE, message, args, **kwargs)


setLoggerClass(AioLogger)
```

class a:

```
import logging
from AioLogger import AioLogger
from b import b

LOG = AioLogger(logging.getLogger('myapp'))
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        LOG.setLevel(AioLogger.TRACE)

        # create a file handler
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)-15s: line %(lineno)-5d: %(levelname)-8s: '
                                           '%(funcName)-50s: %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        LOG.addHandler(file_handler)

        # create console handler
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(AioLogger.TRACE)
        console_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)-15s: line %(lineno)-5d: %(levelname)-8s: '
                                              '%(funcName)-50s: %(message)s')
        console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
        LOG.addHandler(console_handler)

        LOG.trace('trace')
        LOG.debug('debug')
        LOG.info('info')
        LOG.warning('warning')
        LOG.error('error')
```

class b:

```
import logging
from AioLogger import AioLogger

LOG = AioLogger(logging.getLogger('myapp'))
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        LOG.trace('trace')
        LOG.debug('debug')
        LOG.info('info')
        LOG.warning('warning')
        LOG.error('error')
```

Adding following at the end of the file from class a:

```
ls = a()
cls2 = b()
```

and running it, it produces following output:

```
[2019-05-05 18:03:19,908] a.py           : line 27   : TRACE   : __init__                                          : trace
[2019-05-05 18:03:19,908] a.py           : line 28   : DEBUG   : __init__                                          : debug
[2019-05-05 18:03:19,908] a.py           : line 29   : INFO    : __init__                                          : info
[2019-05-05 18:03:19,908] a.py           : line 30   : WARNING : __init__                                          : warning
[2019-05-05 18:03:19,908] a.py           : line 31   : ERROR   : __init__                                          : error
warning
error
```

For some reason the defined properties for the custom logger class are just vanishing. I guess the error is somewhere in my custom logger class, as getting the "default" logger via logging.getlogger('myapp') just works fine - but it does not provide the needed TRACE loglevel (hence the custom logger class, which BTW I found somewhere on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

The Logger class is not a singleton. In class `a`, you call `LOG = AioLogger(logging.getLogger('myapp'))`. *This returns an instance of `AioLogger`, not the class*. Thus, in the subsequent code you customize that instance, not the class.

If you want `AioLogger` to have those handlers and formatters, it must be defined within the class, as properties of it. Then, every time you instantiate it, all those properties will be brought along.